# Handling dynamic content within model property MVC4 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am storing html inside a JSON blob in my database which deserializes to a dynamic, `ViewCargo`, in C#. At the view level, I then use something like `@Model.ViewCargo.PromoDetails` to output the HTML.

This is working great, except in a scenario where I need to update content within the dynamic property. An example of that might be some messaging inside a paragraph tag that includes an anchor tag where the href attribute needs to be set based on the user that is loading the page, such as:

```
<p>Thank you for coming back to our promotion! It looks like you have already 
received a promotional card for this promotion! You can click 
<a href="[need to inject URL here]" target="blank">here</a> to retrieve 
your promotional gift card!</p>
```

In this case, the URL is coming out of a call to the database that looks up the user & promotion and determines the user has already joined this promo. As such, I want to offer them a link to retrieve their existing card (instead of issuing a new one).

One of the things I've considered is putting in a placeholder in my json'd HTML and using String.Replace. For example:

```
string existingUrl = db.UserAlreadySubmitted(userId,promoId);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(existingUrl)) {
    Campaign.ViewCargo.PromoDetails = Campaign.ViewCargo.PromoDetails.Replace("[URLPlaceholder]",existingUrl);
}
return View(Campaign);
```

Since I have a central controller that handles view loading for dozens of views, I'd like to avoid clogging up my controller method with code like this. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: what does your view look like?

Comment: For the sake of this example, you could assume it was simply `@model Social.Campaign` as the model type declaration and `@Model.ViewCargo.PromoDetails`. Those two alone describe the situation I'm in.

Answer (score 0):

If your link Url is the product of call(s) to your database, you should really place those calls inside the Controller or the ViewModel, and use Routing to generate the appropriate Url.

For example:

#### View Model

```
public class PromoViewModel {
    private readonly YourDataSourceType context;

    public PromoViewModel(YourDataSourceType context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int UserId {
        get { // get the user id }
    }

    public int PromoId {
        get { // get the promo id }
    }
}
```

#### Controller Action

```
public ActionResult TheViewName() {
    PromoViewModel model = new PromoViewModel(DatabaseContext);
    return View(model);
}
```

#### The View

```
@model The.Namespace.To.PromoViewModel

<p>Thank you for coming back to our promotion! It looks like you have already 
received a promotional card for this promotion! You can click 
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Controller Name", action = "Action Name", userId = Model.UserId, promoId = Model.PromoId })" target="blank">here</a> to retrieve 
your promotional gift card!</p>
```

That way, you're hrefing your link to a **routed action** instead of a **hard coded url**. If you refactor your routes differently, the link wont break.

Comment: Sorry, I should have pointed out that this URL is not an internal URL, so therefore wouldn't be handled by the route handler.I simply need to inject the URL into my link - could do it with JavaScript too... just wondering if there's a way to handle it at the controller level

Comment: @ScottSilvi: Where is the link coming from? Are you drawing it up from the database? Or is it a fixed, well known address? Or are you glueing it together with data from the model?

Comment: The link is generated via a helper method in our domain layer - pass in an Id, out pops the card URL. It's a URL that we own, but it's hosted by a different domain.